# Is &decltype(object)::memfn a misuse?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I had some class like this:

```
class Test {
public:
    bool bar(int &i, char c) // some arguments are passed by ref, some are by value
    {/*...*/}
    bool foo(/*...*/)
    {}
};
```

And I don't want repeatly call bar1/bar2, etc. and then check the return value again and again, so I wrote a macro and variadic template to handle those things

```
#define help_macro(object, memfn, ...) help_func(#object "." #memfn, \
        object, &decltype(object)::memfn, ##__VA_ARGS__)

template<class T, typename Func, typename... Args>
void help_func(char const * name, T &&object, Func memfn, Args&&... args)
{
    auto ret = (object.*memfn)(forward<Args>(args)...);
    cout<<name<<":\t"
        <<(ret ? "OK" : "Oops")  // maybe I'll throw an exception here  
        <<endl;
}
```

And use it like this

```
int i = 0;
Test t;
help_macro(t, bar, i, 'a');
```

It works on g++-4.7/Debian, but ICC13.0/Win refuses to compile it(a very strange error message)

> main.cpp(37): error : type name is not allowed
>           help_macro(t, bar, i, 'a');
>           ^
>   main.cpp(37): error : expected a ")"
>           help_macro(t, bar, i, 'a');
>           ^

I turn on the C++11 for ICC, and confirmed that ICC13 support variadic template and decltype
Do I use it incorrectly or it's ICC's problem?

Comment: I am not sure, but I would suggest avoiding the forwarding. You don't seem to be inspecting the arguments, so you could avoid the forwarding and do just `#define help_macro(call, ...) help_function(#call, call(__VA_ARGS__))` and `template <typename ReturnT> help_function(const char *name, T &&ret) { cout << name << ":\t" <<(ret ? "OK" : "Oops") <<endl; }`. It's a bit shorter, more general (works for static functions too) and does not strain the compiler so much.

Comment: help_macro(t, bar, i, 'a');. you mean bar2 right? There is no 'bar' in 'Test' (as indicated in error message)

Comment: this looks like the type of hack to be avoided if you want to maintain readability (by humans).

Comment: Sorry guys, it's my mistake.
PS, could I use <s> </s> in code? seems it's useless. It's my first post to stackoverflow :(

Comment: hi, @JanHudec Thanks for your advice, your codes are really clear and clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Having actually bothered to test my theory it turns out I was wrong, in that context `decltype(t)` is `Test` as can be shown by a `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t), Test>::value, "not a reference")`

So ICC (or the EDG front end it uses) probably just doesn't properly support using `decltype` in nested-name-specifiers, which was changed by [DR 743](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#743)

Using `std::decay` *does* make ICC accept it though, and so is a useful workaround.

**Original, wrong, answer**:

I think ICC is right here, `decltype(object)` is actually `Test&` and a reference type cannot have members, so `&decltype(t)::memfn` is ill-formed.

The code can be simplified to:

```
struct Test {
    void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  auto p = &decltype(t)::foo;
}
```

Which G++ and Clang accept, but ICC rejects, correctly IMHO.

You can fix it by using `std::remove_reference` or `std::decay`

```
#include <type_traits>

// ...

Test t;
auto p = &std::decay<decltype(t)>::type::foo;
```

Comment: Off-topic maybe, but why doesn't the `::` operator discard references? Would an implicit decay be undesirable sometimes?

Comment: Good question, I don't know the answer. [expr.prim.general] specifically says "The type denoted by a decltype-specifier in a nested-name-specifier shall be a class or enumeration type."

Comment: Oh actually that's a post-C++11 DR http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1440, this is also related http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1586, and the change to allow `decltype(T)::mem` was http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#743

Comment: According to that chronology, the late change to C++11 was to allow the grammar production, and the defect report additionally specifies that references are disallowed. So moving forward, `std::decay` is the way to go and actually using the feature per 743 is a bad idea unless you have the declaration on hand, and a bad habit in general.

Comment: yes, I agree. In the specific example in this question `decltype(t)` is not a reference, but in the general case it could be, so using `decay` or `remove_reference` should be either harmless or make the code do the right thing

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is there is no 'bar' function in class Test but not sure as I don't have access to this compiler. However the error message you posted shows there is an attempt to use 'bar'.

The following works on both gcc and clang

```
class Test {
public:
    bool bar1(int &i, char c) // some arguments are passed by ref, some are by value
    {return true;}
    bool bar2(int &i, char c)
    {return true;}
};

#define help_macro(object, memfn, ...) help_func(#object "." #memfn, \
        object, &decltype(object)::memfn, ##__VA_ARGS__)

template<class T, typename Func, typename... Args>
void help_func(char const * name, T &&object, Func memfn, Args&&... args)
{
    auto ret = (object.*memfn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout<<name<<":\t"
        <<(ret ? "OK" : "Oops")  // maybe I'll throw an exception here
        <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    Test t;
    //help_macro(t, bar, i, 'a');
    help_macro(t, bar2, i, 'a');
}
```

Comment: It's a typo, Sorry about that. I copied my code and modified it:(